# MySQl count grouping by 4 columns

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, sum

Basically, this query returns me different values from counts()

```
Geographic Address(city),Office,Device type, Device unique type identifier, number case by device type
0001,1002,ORDENADOR,ORD1234,5 INCIDENCIAS
0001,1002,ORDENADOR,ORD3333,2 INCIDENCIAS
0001,1002,ORDENADOR,ORD2222,1 INCIDENCIAS
0001,1002,TECLADO,TECYYYY,2 INCIDENCIAS
0001,1002,TECLADO,TECXXXX,4 INCIDENCIAS
0001,1002,PANTALLA,PAN0000,1 INCIDENCIAS

Select 
        d.dt as 'Direccion Territorial',
        t.centro as 'Oficina',
        nombrelargo,
        if(length(p.Oficina)=3,concat('0',p.Oficina),p.Oficina) as 'Oficina2',
        p.Tipo_Disp as 'Dispositivo',
        count(p.Tipo_Disp) as 'Nº de partes/Etiqueta',
        p.Etq_Amarilla as 'Etiqueta',
        ------------   count(TOTAL INC DE ESE DISPOSITIVO) ---------------------------,
        ------------   count(TOTAL INC DE ESA OFICINA) ---------------------------

from textcentro t,dtdz d,ppp p
        where 
                t.jcentro03=d.dt and
                t.organizativo='OFIC./AGEN./DELEG.' and
                t.situacion='ABIERTO' and
                t.sociedad='0900' and
                (p.Estado != "Abierto" and p.Estado!= 'Planificado') and
                (month(p.Fecha_y_hora_de_creacion) = 8 and year(Fecha_y_hora_de_creacion)=2013) and
                t.centro=if(length(p.Oficina)=3,concat('0',p.Oficina),p.Oficina)

                GROUP BY d.dt,t.centro,p.Tipo_Disp,p.Etq_Amarilla
```

The grouping:

1 - d.dt ----> Postal code

2 - t.centro ----> Office code

3 - p.Tipo_Disp ----> Device Type

4 - d.Etq_Amarilla ----> Unique identifier for this device

The tables are :

1- textcentro ----> Specific information of the offices

2- dtdz ----> auxiliary table to find the Postal Code of the office

3- ppp ----> Table where we can find all the cases

So now, I want to sum the total number of cases by device type, should be this:

```
Postal Code,Office,Device type, Unique identifier for Device, total number of cases by unique identifier device, total number case by device type, total number case by office

0001,1002,ORDENADOR,ORD1234,5 INCIDENCIAS,8 INC,15
0001,1002,ORDENADOR,ORD3333,2 INCIDENCIAS,8 INC,15
0001,1002,ORDENADOR,ORD2222,1 INCIDENCIAS,8 INC,15
0001,1002,TECLADO,TECYYYY,2 INCIDENCIAS,6 INC,15
0001,1002,TECLADO,TECXXXX,4 INCIDENCIAS,6 INC,15
0001,1002,PANTALLA,PAN0000,1 INCIDENCIAS,1 INC,15
```

I'm trying with sums and counts functions but i dont reach it, i don't have any way to take the last two columns. I think that i can try to take this number by sub-query in the column but the performance will be down too much.

The example would be this... but even i get to finish the query and im waiting around 12-13 minutes.

```
Select 
        d.dt as 'Direccion Territorial',
        t.centro as 'Oficina',
        nombrelargo,
        if(length(p.Oficina)=3,concat('0',p.Oficina),p.Oficina) as 'Oficina2',
        p.Tipo_Disp as 'Dispositivo',
        count(p.Tipo_Disp) as 'Nº de partes/Etiqueta',
        p.Etq_Amarilla as 'Etiqueta',
        (Select count(*) from People_DB pp where pp.Oficina=p.Oficina and pp.Tipo_Disp=Dispositivo and (month(pp.Fecha_y_hora_de_creacion) = 8 and year(pp.Fecha_y_hora_de_creacion)=2013) and (pp.Estado != "Abierto" and pp.Estado!= 'Planificado') )

from textcentro t,dtdz d,ppp p
        where 
                t.jcentro03=d.dt and
                t.organizativo='OFIC./AGEN./DELEG.' and
                t.situacion='ABIERTO' and
                t.sociedad='0900' and
                (p.Estado != "Abierto" and p.Estado!= 'Planificado') and
                (month(p.Fecha_y_hora_de_creacion) = 8 and year(Fecha_y_hora_de_creacion)=2013) and
                t.centro=if(length(p.Oficina)=3,concat('0',p.Oficina),p.Oficina)

                GROUP BY d.dt,t.centro,p.Tipo_Disp,p.Etq_Amarilla
```

Sorry for my poor english, maybe this post is unintelligible

Comment: may be yo have to add indexes look at the EXPLAIN O/P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I make some suggestions:

**First**, your choice of tables looks like this:

```
 from textcentro t,dtdz d,ppp p
```

For the sake of clarity I suggest you employ explicit `JOIN` statements instead.  For example

```
 FROM textcentro AS t
 JOIN dtdx       AS d      ON t.jcentro03=d.dt
 JOIN ppp        AS p      ON  XXXXXXXXX
```

You may want to use `LEFT JOIN` in cases for example, where there might be no corresponding row in dtdx to go with a row in textcentro.

I *cannot tell* from your sample query what the `ON` constraint for the `JOIN` to ppp should be.  I have shown that with `XXXXXXXXX` in my code above. I think your condition is this:

```
 t.centro=if(length(p.Oficina)=3,concat('0',p.Oficina),p.Oficina)
```

but that is a nasty expression to compute, and therefore very slow. It looks like your t.centro is a char column containing an integer with leading zeros, and your p.Oficina is the same but without the leading zeros.  Instead of adding the leading zero to p.Oficina, try stripping it from the t.centro column.

```
 CAST(t.centro AS INTEGER) = p.Oficina
```

Keep in mind that without a simple `JOIN` constraint you get a combinatorial explosion:  m times n rows. This makes things slow and possibly wrong.

So, your table selection becomes:

```
 FROM textcentro AS t
 JOIN dtdx       AS d      ON t.jcentro03=d.dt
 JOIN ppp        AS p      ON CAST(t.centro AS INTEGER) = p.Oficina
```

**Second**, your date/time search expressions are not built for speed.  Try this:

```
      p.Fecha_y_hora_de_creacion >= '2013-08-01'
  AND p.Fecha_y_hora_de_creacion <  '2013-08-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

If you have an index on your `p.Fecha...` column, this will permit a range-scan search on that column.

**Third**, this item in your `SELECT` list is killing performance.

```
(Select count(*) 
   from People_DB pp 
  where pp.Oficina=p.Oficina 
    and pp.Tipo_Disp=Dispositivo
    and (month(pp.Fecha_y_hora_de_creacion) = 8 
    and year(pp.Fecha_y_hora_de_creacion)=2013) 
    and (pp.Estado != "Abierto" and pp.Estado!= 'Planificado') )
```

Refactor this to be a virtual table in your JOIN list, as follows.

```
 (SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumPersonas,
         Oficina,
         Tipo_Disp
    FROM People_DB
   WHERE Fecha_y_hora_de_creacion >= '2013-08-01'
     AND Fecha_y_hora_de_creacion <  '2013-08-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
     AND Estado != 'Abierto'
     AND Estado != 'Planificado 
   GROUP BY Oficina, Tipo_Disp
 ) AS pp_summary ON (    pp_summary.Oficina=p.Oficina
                     AND pp_summary.Tipo_Disp=Dispositivo)
```

So, this is your final list of tables.

```
 FROM textcentro AS t
 JOIN dtdx       AS d      ON t.jcentro03=d.dt
 JOIN ppp        AS p      ON CAST(t.centro AS INTEGER) = p.Oficina
 JOIN  (
         SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumPersonas,
                Oficina,
                Tipo_Disp
           FROM People_DB
          WHERE Fecha_y_hora_de_creacion >= '2013-08-01'
            AND Fecha_y_hora_de_creacion <  '2013-08-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
            AND Estado != 'Abierto'
            AND Estado != 'Planificado 
       GROUP BY Oficina, Tipo_Disp
 ) AS pp_summary ON (    pp_summary.Oficina=p.Oficina
                     AND pp_summary.Tipo_Disp=Dispositivo)
```

Three of these tables are "physical" tables, and the fourth is a "virtual" table, constructed as a summary of the physical table called People_DB.

You can include

```
     pp_summary.NumPersonas
```

in your SELECT list.

**Fourth**, avoid the nonstandard extensions to MySQL `GROUP BY` functionality, and use standard SQL. Read this for more information.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

**Fifth,** add appropriate indexes to your tables.

Comment: I have tried your suggestions but even i dont get to finish the query

Comment: Do you mean the query did not complete running?

Comment: I made it! Thanks to u guy !